# Accessing feature extent of feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, feature-class

How can i access to feature extent of a feature class and change the extent using arcpy ?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can access the feature extent of a feature class by using the [Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//018v00000013000000) function

```
import arcpy, os

fc = r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\fc'

desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)

xmin = desc.extent.XMin
xmax = desc.extent.XMax
ymin = desc.extent.YMin
ymax = desc.extent.YMax

print "xmin: %s \nxmax: %s \nymin: %s \nymax: %s" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

---

You can change the [output extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/es/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000009000000) in the environment settings (source Esri).

> The Output Extent environment setting defines what features or rasters
>   will be processed by a tool. This setting is useful when you need to
>   process only a portion of a larger dataset. You can think of this
>   setting as a rectangle used to select input features and rasters for
>   processing. Any feature or raster that passes through the rectangle
>   will be processed and written to output. Note that the rectangle is
>   used only to select features, not clip them. The extent of the output
>   dataset will typically be larger than the Output Extent setting to
>   account for features that pass through the extent rectangle.

```
import arcpy

# Set the extent environment using a keyword.
arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"

# Set the extent environment using the Extent class.
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(-107.0, 38.0, -104.0, 40.0)

# Set the extent environment using a space-delimited string.
arcpy.env.extent = "-107.0 38.0 -104.0 40.0"
```

If you are referring to changing the actual geometry of a feature class, which may subsequently alter the extent, then your best is to use a Cursor.